# testing cipher suite using openssl for tomcat server is resulting in wrong manner

Tags: ssl, openssl

I am using tomcat 6.0.28. and I have configured connector with "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA" but when i am testing whether cipher is suited as follows I am getting following error:

```
  > F:\validation\20141204202945-openssl-1.0.1j-64\openssl-1.0.1j.64\bin>openssl s_client -connect localhost:9251 -cipher ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA 
   >   WARNING: can't open config file: c:/openssl-1.0.1j.64/ssl/openssl.cnf
  > Loading'screen' into random state - done CONNECTED(00000160)
    > 6616:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert
handshake failure:.\ssl\s23_clnt.c:770:
    >     --- no peer certificate available
    >     --- No client certificate CA names sent
    >     --- SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 163 bytes
    >     --- New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE) Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported Compression: NONE Expansion: NONE
```

Please help me in this case

Comment: Look at the error messages at the server and please don't cross post to multiple sites.

Comment: sorry, for my mistake. But I couldnt get by seeing message  what went wrong . but same comment works fine for other websites. am I doing mistake in connector configuration?

Comment: The command on the client side is correct. That's why you have to look at the server side for errors. Are you even sure that the other end talks SSL? Did you check with other ciphers or let openssl just use the default ciphers?

Comment: @Steffen if s_client reports an alert, the server is doing SSL/TLS. OP: from your syntax I assume you are using Tomcat **without** APR aka tcnative and thus with **Java** SSL/TLS (JSSE), so what version of Java and what if any crypto providers in Java?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: You are right. But it looks like that the "handshake error" was sent as the only response to the ClientHello. If the cipher would not match I would expect a "no shared ciphers". But maybe the server was configured to use the cipher even if it does not have support for ECC at all, or at least not for the curves offered by the openssl client.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply, actually I use JSSE for tomcat connector, my jdk version is 1.6 and I have disable ssl3(only supporting TLSv1.0). I checked jdk 1.6 and TLSv1.0 support following ciphers,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, so i ve configured it as ciphers. am I wrong in configuration? supporting cipher is related to ssl certifcate in anyway?

Comment: Java 6 and later *JSSE* supports ECDHE suites *only* if there is an ECC crypto provider which Java 6 does not include; 7 and 8 do. Within ECDHE, support for ECHDE-RSA versus ECDHE-ECDSA depends on your key&cert, but that rarely matters. See more in related question http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/74270/which-forward-secrecy-cipher-suites-are-supported-for-tls1-0-protocols  .